# How to support same url pattern with different HTTP methods Angular 6 using wiremock

Tags: angular, angular-services, wiremock

I am using wiremock to mock my services for my Angular app.
I have two services with same signature

```
    GET /.*/clients/*/disclosure
    POST /.*/clients/*/disclosure

{
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "urlPattern": "/.*/clients/*/disclosure"

    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "bodyFileName": "mock/get-success.json",
        "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }
}
{
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "urlPattern": "/.*/clients/*/disclosure"

    },
    "response": {
        "status": 201,
        "bodyFileName": "mock/post-success.json",
        "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }
}
```

But when ever I do a POST request the Get request is initiated.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: In wiremock WS signature, the second method is PUT not POST. Maybe that's the reason GET request is initiated every time.

Comment: @MukeshKumar Its a typo. It is a POST request..I have edited the Question

Comment: Can you share your angular service code? I have tested the same case and it is working fine. Take a look at code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wryh7x

Comment: I would recommend to use a network traffic analyser tool like smsniff or WireShark to see what is actually happening. Like @Mukesh I'm not seeing any reason for conflict of the WireMock Rules and would suspect it to be a code issue.

Comment: Its seems there was some prob with "urlPattern": "/.*/clients/*/disclosure" .I changed it to "urlPattern": "/.*/clients/.*/disclosure" and it worked fine.